# Print accentuation (UTF-8) Zebra cpcl Java/Android

Tags: java, android, zebra-printers

I m trying print in ZEBRA Imz320 using cpcl language but i have some trouble with accentuation (UTF-8)

i tried:

```
myCpclContentLabel.getBytes("CP1251");
```

and not work

i read this documentation [CPCL command manual](http://www.maxatec-europe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/CPCL_Commands_Manual_1.1.pdf)

```
O. COUNTRY/CODE PAGE Command
The COUNTRY control command substitutes the appropriate character set for the specified country,
Format {command} {name}
Command & option
{command} COUNTRY
{name} USA
GERMANY
FRANCE
SWEDEN
SPAIN
NORWAY
CHINA (double byte encoding)
ITALY
CP850
UK
BIG5 (Traditional Chinese; double byte encoding)
JAPAN-S (Simplified Japanese fonts; double byte encoding
```

but i don't know what i ll use to print correct my text with accentuation (UTF-8)

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it using in the OutputStream of BluetoothSocket an encodint to ISO-8859-1 for printing Spanish characters.

```
      String cpclData = " ! 0 200 200 1240 1\n" +
      "TEXT 7 3 300 200 Dirección \r\n"

      outputStream.write(cpclData.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you couldn't use ZPL? ZPL supports UTF-8 natively.

Comment: yes, i allredy have a lot of reports done in CPCL, impossible for me redo all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your String to a byte array using the character encoding `String.getBytes(String charsetName)` is not enough to make your printer accept the encoding. It just guarantee the first part: your String in Java won't be broken when is converted to bytes.

The last step is to use CPCL ENCODING command to it. Here is a code example from the [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/cpcl-pm-en.pdf):

`! 0 200 200 200 1
ENCODING GB18030
TEXT GBUNSG24.CPF 0 20 30 Font: GBUNSG24 ‚t‚u
ENCODING ASCII
TEXT 7 0 20 80 Font 7, Size 0
PRINT`